# Range doesn't conflict with other ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have to make a rails validation that handles the following situation:

I have a set of ranges, and I need to know if the asked range has a conflict with any of these ranges at all.

For example, I have the following ranges:

- (0..3000)
- (3000..4000)
- (4000..5000)
- (6000..7000)

  - 1..10 would be in conflict, since this range is already included in 0..3000
  - 1..3100 would be in conflict, since this range is included, partially, between 0..3000 and 3000.4000
  - 2800..4500 would be in conflict, since this range is included, partially, between 0..3000, 3000..4000 and 4000..5000
  - 5000..6000 wouldn't be in conflict

The only thing I have achieved is the first and easiest case with this line:

```
def is_not_conflictive_range?
  ranges = ServicePrice.where(property: self.property).pluck(:from_value, :to_value).map { |range| range.first..range.second }
  conflictive_range = ranges.find do |range|
     range.include? (self.from_value..self.to_value)
  end
  errors.add(:service_price, "range from #{self.from_value} to #{self.to_value} is including in existing range from #{conflictive_range.first} to #{conflictive_range.last}") if conflictive_range
end
```

But I can't really figure out how to handle the other cases in a simple way.

Comment: you need to prove this via code? The simple answer is they do have a conflict, since a range with two dots like `1..10` includes *both* 1 and 10, whether one with three dots like `1...10` only includes 1 and *not* 10

Comment: Yep, I have to code it, it should be a Rails Validation.

Comment: what do you mean by "Rails Validation"? Model validation? Or like a function that proves it? And why would you need such function?

Comment: Ok the code helps a bit

Comment: Sorry. It's a model validation. It's a model that represents a sort of range, and I have to make sure that a new range doesn't conflict with each other.

Comment: So you want to validate new entries that they don't conflict with an already existing range?

Comment: Yup, I need to cover the cases that I mentioned in the examples above.

Comment: That's a cool question, I'll see if I can figure it out :), maybe you should make the task a bit more clear

Comment: 5000..6000 is included partially in 4000..5000 and 6000..7000 as they have 5000 and 6000 included in the range

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those questions that's straightforward when viewed the right way, but otherwise messy and complex. After a couple of false starts I addressed the question, "how can an overlap be avoided?

I have assumed that the ranges in the array are ordered in the sense that the end of each range is not greater than the start of the next and the start of each range is not less than the end of previous. This is what you have in your example. If that condition does not hold, the first step would be to modify the array so that this condition holds, which would not be difficult.

**Code**

```
def no_overlap?(arr, range)
  range.last  <= arr.first.first ||
  range.first >= arr.last.last   ||
  arr.each_cons(2).any? { |r1,r2|
    range.first >= r1.last && range.last <= r2.first }
end
```

**Examples**

```
arr = [1000..3000, 3000..4000, 4000..4000, 4000..5000, 6000..7000]

no_overlap?(arr,    1..1010) #=> false
no_overlap?(arr, 2800..4500) #=> false
no_overlap?(arr, 2500..5500) #=> false
no_overlap?(arr, 5000..6000) #=> true
no_overlap?(arr,    0..500)  #=> true
no_overlap?(arr, 8000..9000) #=> true
```

Comment: This is a great answer, and is most likely what Matías wants. +1 I'm still unsure if he wants to have `5000..6000` to return *true* or *false*. Normal ranges would conflict...

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd rename the function to something more readable. I chose `valid_range`.

You came pretty close with your code, my end result is:

```
def valid_range?
  ranges = ServicePrice.where(property: self.property).pluck(:from_value, :to_value).map { |range| range.first..range.second }

  ranges.each do |range|
    # check if either values are part of the range
    if range.include?(from_value) || range.include?(to_value)
      # invalid, so return false
      return false
    end
  end

  # if it 'survived' the loop return true
  return true
end
```

So it loops through all existing loops and returns false on an error.

Though with this your currently existing ranges aren't valid since `4000..5000` is part of the `3000..4000` range.

A solution to this would be to use ranges with three dots instead. So adjust the `map` part to

```
.map { |range| range.first...range.second }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check:

- If the first number of the range is included in any range;
- If the last number of the range is included in any range;
- If any range is included itself in the selected range.

So, you can change your code to:

```
conflictive_range = ranges.find_all do |range|
  range.include?(self.from_value) ||
  range.include?(self.to_value) ||
  (range.first > self.from_value && range.last < self.to_value)
end
```

And as I commented 5000..6000 will be in conflict because there is a range with 5000 and other with 6000.

Comment: If the range being tested is `7000..8000`, this presumably would return `6000..7000`, but it is not a conflict when an endpoint of the range being tested is an endpoint of one of the ranges of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I do this in plain ruby. (Edited: thanks for the help of Cary Swoveland)

First, define a conflict? method that show if 2 ranges are overlaped (this can be do at model level)

```
class Range
  def conflict?(other)
    self.begin < other.end && self.end > other.begin
  end
end
```

Then I define an invalid_range method that returns true if the range is invalid for the set:

```
def invalid_range(range, set)
  set.any? {|s| s.conflict?(range)}
end
```

Verify with user data:

```
set = [(0..3000), (3000..4000), (4000..5000), (6000..7000)]

cases = [(1..10), (1..3100), (2800..4500), (5000..6000)]

# verifying:
cases.each {|c| puts "testing range: #{c} on set result: #{invalid_range(c,set)}"}
```

Output of cases.each ...

```
testing range: 1..10 on set result: true
testing range: 1..3100 on set result: true
testing range: 2800..4500 on set result: true
testing range: 5000..6000 on set result: false
```

If you like this approach, I think you can modify your models to do the same. If you have problems with this, please publish your models and I help you.

I hope it helps.

Edited: change invalid for invalid_range because it isn't AR compatible.

Comment: This returns "conflict on 2001..3000 with 2010..2020" for `range = 2000..2001`.

Comment: Yes, it's because 2001..3000 is overlapped with 2010..2020 (at least 1 element in each rage in comun. Is that what is the asker searching for?

Comment: That `2001..3000` and `2010..2020` have at  least one (interior) element in common is irrelevant. The question is whether a given range has either: a) at least one non-endpoint element that is in at least one range in the array; or b) an endpoint that is in at least one range in the array and is not an endpoint of that array. If either condition holds, there is a conflict for the given range.

Comment: Thank you Cary, I'll take my time to study this topic, and then fix my answer or comment.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to check for inclusion of ranges in Ruby, just check the boundaries.

```
def valid_range?
  ranges = ServicePrice.where(property: self.property).pluck(:from_value, :to_value).map { |range| [range.first, range.second] }

  conflict = nil
  conflict = ranges.map do |min, max|
    [
      self.from_value > min && self.from_value < max,
      self.to_value > min && self.to_value < max
    ].any?
  end.index(true)

  errors.add(:service_price, "range from #{self.from_value} to #{self.to_value} is including in existing range from #{ranges[conflict].first} to #{ranges[conflict].last}") unless conflict.blank?
end
```

I think I have covered all the possible cases, but not sure at the moment.